# Nan in summary histogram for: FirstStageFeatureExtractor

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run the tensorflow object detection api. I have made a dataset with 1 class using labelImg and then converting the xmls to tfrecord files. Some information:

```
os: Ubuntu 16.04
gpu: nvidia geforce 1080Ti & 1060
tensorflow version: 1.3.0
training model: faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco (although I have tried others)
Classes: 1
```

I then run `train.py` and training begins. When I get ~step 355 I get the error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:global step 363: loss = 1.4006 (0.294 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 163, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 159, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/ucfadng/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 332, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 767, in train
    sv.stop(threads, close_summary_writer=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 792, in stop
    stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 296, in stop_on_exception
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 494, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 994, in run_loop
    self._sv.global_step])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma_1
         [[Node: SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma_1/tag, SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma/read)]]
         [[Node: Loss/RPNLoss/map/TensorArray_2/_1353 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_5239_Loss/RPNLoss/map/TensorArray_2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma_1', defined at:
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 163, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 159, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/ucfadng/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 295, in train
    global_summaries.add(tf.summary.histogram(model_var.op.name, model_var))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py", line 192, in histogram
    tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 129, in _histogram_summary
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Nan in summary histogram for: SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma_1
         [[Node: SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma_1 = HistogramSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma_1/tag, SecondStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma/read)]]
         [[Node: Loss/RPNLoss/map/TensorArray_2/_1353 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_5239_Loss/RPNLoss/map/TensorArray_2", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

My label map is:

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'rail'
}
```

The pipeline used was downloaded from: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config

I have had a look at the TFRecord files and look as expected which leads be to think this is something to do with the initial dataset. But what specifically would cause this error?

My dataset consists of 250 clear images containing railway tracks. I have labelled sections of the tracks so each image has ~20/30 labelled objects.

So far the main thing I have tried is lowering learning rates and changing batch size but these did not solve the problem.

Any help in solving this would be very appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now updated to `version: 1.4.0` and this is no longer a problem. I did not change anything else. Perhaps this was a bug with `version: 1.3.0`. I will leave this up just in case anyone has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be an error with tensorflow itself, i believe it has something to do with your system running out of memory.

Setting *train* to *false* in *batch_norm* (within your pipeline.config file) appears to overcome this problem.

It should look something like this:

```
 batch_norm {
          decay: 0.999
          center: true
          scale: true
          epsilon: 0.001
          train: false
        }
```

Hope this helped.